# Camunda Http-Connector create incident for error status-code

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

In our company we have web-services and use the camunda-workflow engine for orchestration.
So each “script-task” can only call web-services and I have only the modeler to configure it (No Java-Implementation etc.).

Now my problem is, that I can’t find a working way to evaluate the response status code and create in case of a status code != 200 || statusCode != 201 an incident.

Following a simple example workflow:

[image]

The `generate`-Script-Task is configured as `Asynchronouse Before`:

[image]

How can I Archive that in case of an response-statuscode != 200 || response-statusCode != 201 an Incident is recreated?:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a really good documentation that clarifies all the questions about http-connector handling:

[Documentation](https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/Make-Rest-Calls-From-Camunda-Example#connectors)